# native app talking directly to db

Tags: android, ios, http, elasticsearch

I'm making an ios app, with ElasticSearch as the db. Since ES exposes an http api, technically I can have the client talk directly to the db without routing it through an app server. I would never do this in Javascript, since the user can view the source and see the credentials. Since ios/android apps are compiled and users can't view their source code, is it safe to have the app talk directly to the db or are there any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Security via obscurity (hiding the API calls by not having them in JavaScript) is never the answer. What's to stop somebody from just sniffing the traffic via WireShark or other similar software and then mapping your API that way?

You should never make your Elasticsearch installation visible to the outside world, ES is built around search, not security.

You'll have to build a wrapper with some baked in authentication if you want to do it properly and securely. The main reason for this is that (you even said it yourself) Elasticsearch is a database, kind of, and you wouldn't go making your database public facing now would you.

As a side note, there is https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty but I've never used it and so couldn't recommend it. I'd stick with the wrapper...