# Secure access to elasticsearch server

Tags: security, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch running on my windows server. I have also add to it the following plugins:
-kibana
-head

I would like to secure all the access. At the moment, when you have the server name, you can access to the elasticsearch engine, explore the data via kibana and delete data via head.
Is it possible to require password when you try to access to the following links:

```
-http://hostname:9200/
-http://hostname:9200/_plugin/head
-http://hostname:9200/_plugin/kibana
```

Comment: See previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956062/authentication-in-elasticsearch

Comment: This question is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245123/native-app-talking-directly-to-db/23247216